# Gate opener code help - should be working

Tags: code-review

Can anyone see any errors in my code that would affect the opening command? Upon first power up the open command (remoteA) works fine.

After that the opening command does what its supposed to except it only momentarily fires "digitalWrite (power, LOW)" command.  It should be set LOW for the same amount of time as "digitalWrite (openGate, LOW)", but it doesnt.

Strange thing is, the close command code is almost identical and it always works as it should, no problems.

Any suggestions? (hopefully the code pastes in here ok, its acting weird)

```
/*
 *  Swing Gate Opener with 2Ch remote, gate lock, motor, buzzer, amp monitor
and two independent limit switches
 *
 *  By Darren Clarke
 *
 */
int current = A0;  // monitor motor current
int buzzer = 3;  // operation buzzer
int power = 5;  // 24v power on/off
int remoteOpen = 6;  // remote button A to digital pin 6
int remoteClose = 7;  // remote button B to digital pin 7
int openGate = 8;  // open gate to motor on digital pin 8
int closeGate = 9;  // close gate to motor on digital pin 9
int gateLock = 10;  // gate lock connected to digital pin 10

// variables
int openRelay = 0;  // variable to store the motor direction
int closeRelay = 0;  // variable for previous motor direction
int remoteA = 0;  // variable for remote A condition
int remoteB = 0;  // variable for remote B condition
int lock = 0;  // varialbe for gate lock
int mA = 0;  // variable for motor current
unsigned long previousMillisA = 0;
unsigned long previousMillisB = 0;
unsigned long currentMillisA = 0;
unsigned long currentMillisB = 0;

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);   // sets the digital pin 4 as output
    pinMode(power, OUTPUT);   // sets the digital pin 5 as output
    pinMode(remoteOpen, INPUT);   // sets the digital pin 6 as input
    pinMode(remoteClose, INPUT);   // sets the digital pin 7 as input
    pinMode(openGate, OUTPUT);   // sets the digital pin 8 as output
    pinMode(closeGate, OUTPUT);   // sets the digital pin 9 as output
    pinMode(gateLock, OUTPUT);   // sets the digital pin 10 as output
    digitalWrite(closeGate, HIGH);   // sets relay to open
    digitalWrite(openGate, HIGH);   // sets relay to open
    digitalWrite(power, HIGH);   // sets relay to open
    digitalWrite(gateLock, HIGH);   // sets relay to open
    analogWrite(buzzer, 0);   // sets buzzer off
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    remoteA = digitalRead(remoteOpen);   // read remote A input
    remoteB = digitalRead(remoteClose);   // read remote B input
    openRelay = digitalRead(openGate);   // read state of openGate
    closeRelay = digitalRead(closeGate);   // read state of closeGate
    lock = digitalRead(gateLock);   // read state of gate lock
    mA = analogRead(current);   // read value of motor current
    currentMillisA = millis();
    currentMillisB = millis();
    Serial.print("aIn ");
    Serial.print(remoteA);
    Serial.print(", bIn ");
    Serial.print(remoteB);
    Serial.print(", Open ");
    Serial.print(openRelay);
    Serial.print(", Close ");
    Serial.print(closeRelay);
    Serial.print(", Lock ");
    Serial.print(lock);
    Serial.print(", mA ");
    Serial.print(mA);
    Serial.print(", cur ");
    Serial.print(currentMillisA);
    Serial.print(", prev ");
    Serial.print(previousMillisA);
    Serial.println(" ");

// to open the gate
    if ((remoteA == HIGH) && (remoteB == LOW)) {
        delay(500);   // time for gate direction reversal
        digitalWrite(power, HIGH);   // stops previous movement
        digitalWrite(closeGate, HIGH);   // Stop gate open command
        analogWrite(buzzer, 100);   // starts buzzer
        digitalWrite(gateLock, LOW);   // energize lock open (unlock state)
        delay(500);   // time for lock to open
        digitalWrite(openGate, LOW);   // actuate gate open
        digitalWrite(power, LOW);   //  supplies 24v power
        previousMillisA = millis();  // set time references
        currentMillisA = millis();  // set time references
    }

// to stop open command
    if ((closeRelay == HIGH) && (currentMillisA - previousMillisA) >= 6000) {
        digitalWrite(gateLock, HIGH);   // denergize lock (locked state)
        digitalWrite(openGate, HIGH);   // stop open relay to motor after open
        digitalWrite(power, HIGH);   // remove 24v power
        analogWrite(buzzer, 0);
    }

// to close the gate
    if ((remoteB == HIGH) && (remoteA == LOW)) {
        delay(500);   // time for gate direction reversal
        digitalWrite(power, HIGH);   // stops previous movement
        digitalWrite(gateLock, HIGH);   // de-energize lock on quick reverse
        digitalWrite(openGate, HIGH);   // Stop gate close command
        analogWrite(buzzer, 100);   // starts buzzer
        digitalWrite(closeGate, LOW);   // actuate gate close
        digitalWrite(power, LOW);   // supplies 24v power
        previousMillisB = millis();  // set time references
        currentMillisB = millis();  // set time references
    }

// to stop close command
    if ((openRelay == HIGH) && (currentMillisB - previousMillisB) >= 6000) {
        digitalWrite(closeGate, HIGH);   // stop close relay to motor
        digitalWrite(power, HIGH);   // remove 24v power
        analogWrite(buzzer, 0);
    }

    delay(100);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i figured it out.

Thanks all for your help.

It only happens on the A channel because its first in the series of the code.  The turn off command after the timer isnt specific enough.  The if conditions are met on the B channel so it keeps turning the power off immediately.

I just need be more specific in my if command or make another tweek.

Thanks guys,  your suggestions caused me to do much more digging and code adjustments.

Its working like a peach now.

Thanks.

Comment: Accept your answer to close the question.